# Как увеличить расстояние между ссылками?

Tags: html, css

не могу понять как сделать расстояние между ссылками.

```css
    body{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family: "Nunito Sans";
        
    }
    
    .menu_header{
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-around;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .img_logo{
        padding:75px 0px;
    }
    .a_menu{
        padding: 97px 0px;
        color: #bab8b8;
        font-family: Nunito;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 14.61px;
        margin:0px 50px 0px 0px;
    
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Оболочка документа, указываем язык содержимого -->
    <html lang="ru">
        <head>
            <!-- Заголовок страницы в браузере -->
            <title>test</title>
            <!-- Подключаем CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <!-- Кодировка страницы -->
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="menu_header">
                    <div class="img_logo">
                    <img src="logotip.png" alt="357">
                    </div>
                    <div class="a_menu">
                    <a href="">Home</a>
                    <a href="">Video</a>
                    <a href="">Destinationmenu</a>
                    <a href="">Booking</a>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну а кто стили для тега `<a>` будет определять?

```css
.a_menu a {
      display:   inline-block;
        margin:    0px 10px;
}
```

а то у вас установлен стиль только для блока `a_menu` в котором находятся ссылки `<a>...</a>`, а для них тоже нужен стиль в котором вы и пропишите на каком расстоянии друг от друга они должны находиться и прочие нужные параметры

Comment: Жесть я дурачок, спасибо за помощь!